# Best way to unit test data analysis with database calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a bunch of classes that all look somewhat like this:

```
class FakeAnalysis(Analysis):

    def __init__(self, dbi, metric: str, constraints: dict) -> None:
        super().__init__(dbi)
        self.metric = metric
        self.constraints = constraints.copy()

    def load_data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:

        data = self.dbi.select_data(
            {"val"}, {"period"}, **self.constraints
        )

        return data

    def run(self) -> namedtuple:
        """Do some form of dataframe transformation""""
        data = self.load_data()
        df = data.pivot_table(columns='period',values='val',index='product_tag')
        return namedtuple("res", ['df'])(**{"df": df})
```

They all take in a metric, constraints and a database interface class (dbi) as `__init__` arguments. They all load the data necessary by fetching the data through the dbi and then do some sort of data transformation on the resulting dataframe before returning it as a namedtuple containing the transformed data and any other byproducts (i.e. could be multiple dataframes).

The question is: what is the best way to unit test such code? The errors are usually the result of a combination of constraints resulting in unexpected data that the code does not know how to deal with. Should I just test each class with randomly generated constraints and see if it crashes? Or should I create a mock database interface which returns fixed data for a few different constraints and ensure the class returns the results expected for just these constraints? The latter doesn't seem of much use to me although it would be more along the lines of unit testing best practice... 
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is what occurs to me.

You can validate the data first, and not worry about invalid data in your processing.

You can instead deal with invalid data, by not crashing, but using try blocks to generate reasonable output for the user, or log errors, whatever is proper.

Unit test what *your* code does. Make sure it does what it says. Do it by mocking and inpecting mock calls. Use mocks to return invalid data and test that they trigger the invalid data exceptions you provided.

If you find difficult to express all cases that could be wrong (maybe you have to generalize a bit here because of dealing with very large or infinite possible inputs), it may be useful to stretch the thing with lots of randomly generated data that will show you cases you have not imagined (trust me, this works).

Capture those to a reasonable amount, until (the typical size of your data, or 10x that, or more, you choose) random data does not seem to trigger errors. Keep your random tests running but reduce the tries to make your tests run fast again, while you go on coding the rest of the system.

Of course mock the database access for this.

At anytime you find that data errors still happen, you can fix that case, and increase the random tries to check better. This is better than writing lots of specific cases by hand.